# Why doesn't ES6 prop shortcut trick work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

It was my understanding that if one passed variables as the identical names of React component props that you should use a shortcut form.

Here's an example of the long form, which definitely works:

```
const header = 'I am a Header';
const tip = 'I am a Tip';
const warning = 'I am a Warning';
const error = 'I am an Error';

<InputContainer header={header} tip={tip} warning={warning} error={error}>
```

But this fails to work:

```
<InputContainer header tip warning error>
```

When I did a `console.log` of `header` inside the component, it said its value was `true`.

I guess what I read about this shortcut form way back when was incorrect?

Comment: Dont know react but wouldn't a string value return `true` if not falsey?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it would be `<InputContainer {...{ header, tip, warning, error }}>` to spread an object as JSX props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React props default to `true`. If you pass no value for a prop, it defaults to true